# Friend list access issue

Tags: ios, facebook, friend-function

Is it possible to access friend list of a Facebook user through my iOS app? I would access without any problem for users who accept the app but I want complete friend list. It seems that in the past it was possible and now not possible anymore.

I use :

```
#define FB_IOS_SDK_VERSION_STRING @"3.14.0"
#define FB_IOS_SDK_TARGET_PLATFORM_VERSION @"v2.0"
```

and permission:

```
FBLoginView *loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc]
                           initWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", 
                           @"email",@"user_birthday",@"user_friends"]];
```

Is there a way to access to complete friend list? Do I have to submit my app to Facebook dev team?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to get the complete friend list in API v2.0 and later